# R: optimization algorithm SLSQP

Tags: r

I would like to make a loop on the optimization algorithm slsqp where the objective function depends on two parameters - the second parameter being the loop's variable:

```
library(nloptr)

example <- function(w, j){ return(sum((w + j)^2)) }
```

heq_fun is the equality constraint function on w:

```
heq_fun<-function(w){ 
Mat <- rbind(rep(1,length(w)))
sum <- Mat %*% w
return(sum-1)}
```

Loop:

```
sol_list <- list()

for(j in 1:5){

sol_list[[j]]<-slsqp(fund_weights, fn = example, gr = NULL, lower = rep(0, 16), 
                  upper = rep(1, 16), hin = NULL, hinjac = NULL, heq = heq_fun, 
                  heqjac = NULL, nl.info = FALSE, control =list(stopval = -Inf, 
                  xtol_rel = 1e-9, maxeval = 100000))
}
```

I get:

```
Error in fun(x, ...) : argument "j" is missing, with no default
```

The algorithm does not understand that the second parameter of the function to minimize is also the loop's variable...

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new function in the loop, whit only on one argument. This should help

```
sol_list <- list()

for(j in 1:5){

example <- function(w){ return(sum((w + j)^2)) }

sol_list[[j]]<-slsqp(fund_weights, fn = example, gr = NULL, lower = rep(0,16), 
              upper = rep(1, 16), hin = NULL, hinjac = NULL, heq = heq_fun, 
              heqjac = NULL, nl.info = FALSE, control =list(stopval = -Inf, 
              xtol_rel = 1e-9, maxeval = 100000))
}
```